# CodeIgniter set a column value another existing column value without make a select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table which has columns `status` and `new_status`, so when i change status i put in `new_status` the new value for status.

But i want to have *a backup solution*, so i need an update which set value for *new_status value from column status*.

I use codeigniter, i tried

```
$data = array(
        'new_status'=>Status,//'new_status'=>'Status'//'new_status'=>`Status`
    );
```

But none above worked.

Comment: you need to assign `new_status` value to `status`?? is it??

Comment: No, vice versa, i need to assign `status` value to `new_status`.

Comment: how you getting the data for above fields??

Comment: I don't take any data i just call a function and that fuction need to make a query like that `UPDATE table SET new_status = status WHERE [some condition]`, so i don't use any data values.

Comment: echo `new_status` and see. I think you are not geting any values to these veris

Comment: `'new_status':= 'status'` **try this**

Comment: @Abdulla nop, it's not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79749/discussion-between-abdulla-and-vladutzzz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom query and i called with
 `$query = $this->db->query($text);` 
and
 `$text = "UPDATE table SET new_status = status WHERE [condition]"` 
and it's working 100%.